# PhantomJS: page.open() does not respond when running in REPL

Tags: phantomjs, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to run some phantomJS by sending it in via Standard Input, but my webpage open does not respond.

Here is the javascript I'm trying to execute:

```
require('webpage').create().open('http://google.com', function() { console.log('done'); phantom.exit(); });
```

Pretty straight forward, right?

Put that in a file.js, and use

```
phantomjs.exe file.js
```

and it works, but execute it via REPL

```
phantomjs.exe
phantomjs> require('webpage').create().open('http://google.com', function() { console.log('done'); phantom.exit(); });
```

and it never hits the callback.  Listening to onResourceRequested shows it is being requested the same, but onResourceReceived never comes back.

This is running on windows 7.  Is there anything special I need to do for page.open to work for REPL?

Edit: I should have mentioned, I'm running this from C# in an environment where executing from a file isn't really feasible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same for me.
After a quick look on git repository, it seems it's a known issue : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10518

Comment: Ahh, your github searchy skills are better than mine. Thanks.

Comment: the project seems to be on indefinite hold but here is the 'updated' issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11180